# What does "Insufficient system resources..." error mean?

Tags: java, windows, nio, ioexception, file-copying

This question spans both serverfault and stackoverflow so I just picked this one.

I get the following exception with some simple file copy code.  Its running on Windows Server 2003 x64

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service
at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcher.pwrite0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcher.pwrite(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.write(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.transferFromFileChannel(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.transferFrom(Unknown Source)
at Tools.copy(Tools.java:473)

public static void copy(FileChannel input, FileChannel output) throws IOException {
    final long size = input.size();
    long pos = 0;
    while (pos < size) {
        final long count = (size - pos) > FIFTY_MB ? FIFTY_MB : (size - pos);
        pos += output.transferFrom(input, pos, count);
    }
}
```

The thing is the server that is running this code is brand new and super powerful, so I don't understand what system resource it could possibly be running out of.

This looks like the error described here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304101

But I've tried adding the registry edits to increase kernel memory page size, and that didn't help.

What I really don't get is I've seen code that uses `FileChannel` `transferFrom` with a lot larger chunks of 50 MB.  I've seen that code work for files well over 1 GB in one chunk.  But the file the server is getting stuck on is just 32 MB!

What is going on here?  Is this a problem with `FileChannel` or Windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be related to ["Bug" ID 4938442: Insufficient System Resources When Copying Large Files with NIO FileChannels](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4938442).

> Evaluation: Not a bug.  This is most likely a file-server (or possibly client)
> configuration issue.

> CUSTOMER SUBMITTED WORKAROUND :
>
> - Don't use NIO; we'd prefer to avoid this workaround since
>   NIO offers a significant performance boost for large files
>   (at least when performing local disk-to-local disk copies)

> - We can transfer using a smaller number of bytes.  The
>   actual number of bytes that may be copied without
>   encountering this error seems to differ on Windows XP and
>   Windows 2000 server.  Certainly a value of 32Mb appears to
>   work.